# Can I concatenate different shape tensors with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I'm doing my project about machine learning and I need to merge (concatenate) two tensors that have different shapes.

For more details:

We're trying to concatenate an matrix of tokens with an one hot matrix. tokens pass through an embedding layer so we get a weights matrix with shape like (100, 10, 300).

Finally we need to merge one hot matrix and weights matrix like this:

**(100, 300)** and **(100, 10, 300)** to be **(100, >*11*, 300)**

This is, to append each of the 300 one hot vectors in matrix in the first position of each weight matrix like **(1,300)** + **(1,10,300)** to get a sample of merged values with shape **(1,>*11*,300)**

I actually reached this in a manual form through a loop but it takes too much time so I wanted to know if this is posible through keras or any other similar.

This is the function I wrote so here I reached what I wanted, but if it is possible to do in a better way that doesn't take too much time is the ideal.

```
def join_demo_sentence(X, Demo, embedding, max_length):
  X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
  Demo = pad_sequences(Demo, maxlen=300, padding='post')
  joined = []
  for i, sequence in tqdm(enumerate(X), desc='Joining'):
    demo = Demo[i]
    sequence = embedding.get_weights()[0][sequence]
    join = np.insert(sequence.T, 0, demo, axis=1)
    joined.append(join.T)
  X = np.asarray(joined)
  return X
```

That function loops through the matrix to join demo one hot values and sentence tokens so for final result I get the sentences with the one hot of demographic in first position.

I'm learning about keras so I think there's a way with `keras.layers.Concatenate`

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need:

```
a = tf.random.uniform((100, 10, 300))
b = tf.random.uniform((100, 300))

b = b[:, tf.newaxis, :] # add the second axis
res = tf.concat((a, b), -2)
```